# How to interpret the coefficients for binomial reponse variables in SEM [R, lavaan]

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am learning SEM using the `lavaan` package in R. 
One of the response variables is binomial data (whether or not a participant answered the question accurately), which is predicted by a dummy coded predictor variable.

```
binomial variable <- dummy coded variable
```

I would like to interpret the unstandardized coefficient of this dummy coded variable, but I am not sure whether I can interpret this as a percentage (i.e., when dummy coded variable is 1, the likelihood of participant answered on questions accurately increases by OO%), or as a logit in the same way as logistic regression analyses.

I am not speficying the probability distribution so I am not sure if `lavaan` choose the best distribution automatically..

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lavaan` by default uses the probit link, so you would interpret the coefficient the same way you would with probit regression. To change this behavior to logit, set `link = "logit"` in your `sem()` or `lavaan()` call. See the documentation for `link` in `?lavOptions`. Note that to treat binary response variables as binary and use probit or logit regression, you need to identify them in the `ordered =` argument; otherwise, `lavaan` will use the linear probability model.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and clear answer, @Noah! I appreciate it a lot. :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: Hi, @Noah! I am wondering if you are still here. If so, I would like to ask you another question. Do you have any idea how to transform coefficient of probit model into a percentage (or more interpretable) scale? I realized that `predict()` does not work for the outcome of the `lavaan` package. Let's say, the coefficient for the binary response variable is 0.079. It seems to be z-value...(if I am understanding correctly...), but I do not know how to interpret it. I would appreciate it if I could hear how to transform this into a percentage (or other scales) in a relatively easy way. Thank you.

Comment: That's a whole other question and a big one at that. Interpreting logit and probit coefficients meaningfully is not straightforward. It's too much to describe in a comment, but others have asked on CV. This is one reason to favor the linear probability model.

Comment: I see. Now I understand that it is not that easy to interpret the profit model’s coefficients. I will read into it. Thank you for your explanation, @Noah. I hope you have a good day today.